# Updated Global value cannot be accessed in the slave process in MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

In the below code, I am changing the value of `total_b_points` in master process. I have declared it as global in the code. But this value is not changing in the slave process. This a MPI code working with 2 processes.
Please guide me how can I make it work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include<string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int total_b_points=0;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){        
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int pid;
    int np;   

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);
    if(pid==0){
        std::vector<double> values ={33,334,5,43};
        total_b_points = values.size();
        std::cout << "The value of total_b_points= " <<total_b_points<< std::endl;
    }

    //slave processes
    else{
        std::cout << "Printing the value of total_b_points in Slave  "<< total_b_points<< std::endl;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();      
}

Start: 2023-04-11_15:05:40
The value of total_b_points= 4
Printing the value of total_b_points in Slave  0
Stop: 2023-04-11_15:05:42
```

Comment: Even though they are called global, they are still scoped by the process. Different processes have different global variables. You need to put them into shared memory explicitly. BTW, review the tags you applied, in particular study their descriptions. Also, run your code through an automatic formatting tool, after all you want people to read it.

Comment: FYI, you are programming in C++ since the C language doesn't have `cout`.

Comment: I apologize @UlrichEckhardt for my poorly crafted question. I am using MPI programming. So, I think MPI_send and MPI_recv is the only option in this case?

Comment: I have edited the question @ThomasMatthews and I have removed C tag.

Comment: I highly recommend not using the non-standard `<bits/stdc++.h>`.  IMHO, you should only include the headers that you need and not the behmoth that is `bits/stdc++.h`.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasMatthews for the advice. I will take care of this thing is future.

Comment: Hey @Manu, thanks for your active feedback! If you want, create an answer to your own question. Point is, that this question, although the problem is solved, will appear as one without answer for people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. Thank you everyone. Below solution works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include<string>
#include <atomic>


int total_b_points;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int pid;
    int np;
    
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);

    if(pid==0){
        std::vector<double> values ={33,334,5,43};
        total_b_points = values.size();
        std::cout << "The value of total_b_points= " <<total_b_points<< std::endl;
        // broadcast the value of total_b_points to all other processes
        MPI_Bcast(&total_b_points, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    //slave processes
    else{
        // receive the value of total_b_points from the master process
        MPI_Bcast(&total_b_points, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        

        std::cout << "Printing the value of total_b_points in Slave  "<< total_b_points<< std::endl;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```